# How to aggregate case expression within subquery?

Tags: sql, subquery, case, aggregate

I'm new to stack overflow and have been teaching myself SQL to build custom reports at work. I'd really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction to return an average while using a case expression, here's the story:

I am trying to build a query that returns pricing data from sales invoices. I have a functional report, but I'm trying to standardize the pricing Unit of Measure as our costs are not always set to the same UOM as the sell price. I am limited in which code I can write as I am using an internal report writer that allows us to only write subqueries; I do not have direct access to the DBMS.

I have written a case statement in my subquery that solves the UOM challenge, but I'm stuck trying to aggregate the results.

After changing [View_QB_SalesOrderLine].[Price] to AVG([View_QB_SalesOrderLine].[Price], I tried aggregating my Subquery Case expression by using AVG both before and within the Case statement, but everything I try causes the query to fail.

The only code I have written below is the subquery, everything else is generated by the report writer tool. I greatly appreciate any help I can get!

**Updated with query that caused error, rather that the working code I was trying to build upon...lesson learned.**
This query runs if I remove AVG from the CASE, but returns only [Price] averages grouped by MFR, CATALOG, **and [SPA Cost Conv].** There is a new row for each instance of an item with a unique [SPA Cost Conv]. With AVG before the Case expression, the query errors(Error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) *This message seems generic as it is the only message I've ever seen displayed, no matter the problem with the query. Please keep in mind I can only write subqueries within this tool, all the other code is generated by the tool. I suspect the tool automatically adding the subquery to the Group By has something to do with the error when adding AVG to the subquery.

For context I added an image of what the GUI I'm working with looks like. I write the custom expressions in Notepad++ and paste them into the tool.[Report Writer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEFDI.jpg)

```
SELECT  DISTINCT [Mfr] = [View_QB_SalesOrderLine].[Mfr]
,[CatalogNo] = [View_QB_SalesOrderLine].[CatalogNo]
,[SPA Cost Conv] = (AVG(CASE
    WHEN [Price UOM] = [SPA Cost UOM] 
    THEN [SPA Cost] 
    WHEN [Price UOM] = 'E' AND [SPA Cost UOM] = 'C'
    THEN [SPA Cost]/100
    WHEN [Price UOM] = 'E' AND [SPA Cost UOM] = 'M'
    THEN [SPA Cost]/1000
    WHEN [Price UOM] = 'C' AND [SPA Cost UOM] = 'E'
    THEN [SPA Cost] * 100
    WHEN [Price UOM] = 'C' AND [SPA Cost UOM] = 'M'
    THEN [SPA Cost] / 100
    WHEN [Price UOM] = 'M' AND [SPA Cost UOM] = 'E'
    THEN [SPA Cost] * 1000
    WHEN [Price UOM] = 'M' AND [SPA Cost UOM] = 'C'
    THEN [SPA Cost] * 100
END))
,[Price] = AVG([View_QB_SalesOrderLine].[Price])
,[Price UOM] = [View_QB_SalesOrderLine].[Price UOM]
FROM View_QB_SalesOrderLine
GROUP BY [View_QB_SalesOrderLine].[Mfr]
,[View_QB_SalesOrderLine].[CatalogNo]
,AVG(CASE
    WHEN [Price UOM] = [SPA Cost UOM] 
    THEN [SPA Cost] 
    WHEN [Price UOM] = 'E' AND [SPA Cost UOM] = 'C'
    THEN [SPA Cost]/100
    WHEN [Price UOM] = 'E' AND [SPA Cost UOM] = 'M'
    THEN [SPA Cost]/1000
    WHEN [Price UOM] = 'C' AND [SPA Cost UOM] = 'E'
    THEN [SPA Cost] * 100
    WHEN [Price UOM] = 'C' AND [SPA Cost UOM] = 'M'
    THEN [SPA Cost] / 100
    WHEN [Price UOM] = 'M' AND [SPA Cost UOM] = 'E'
    THEN [SPA Cost] * 1000
    WHEN [Price UOM] = 'M' AND [SPA Cost UOM] = 'C'
    THEN [SPA Cost] * 100
END)
,[View_QB_SalesOrderLine].[Price UOM]
ORDER BY [View_QB_SalesOrderLine].[Mfr]  ASC
,[View_QB_SalesOrderLine].[CatalogNo]  ASC
```

Comment: With only one table you actually don't need to qualify the column references. You should still check into using aliases which will make that easier to read. I think your problem would be fixed by using `group by` though.

Comment: @shawnt00 Thanks for the advice on cleaning up the column references. I usually copy and paste from the tool since I don't have IntelliSense to prevent typos, but you're right it definitely helps readability. I don't think I can use aliases since I can't edit code in the outer query, unless they were needed in the subquery for joins or similar. I just edited the post to clarify the issue. Wondering if you have any additional insight? Thanks again!

Comment: And what is the mysterious error(s) you receive? Please post message in body of question.

Comment: You should not run aggregate queries in `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @Parfait I added the error to the body. The aggregate in the `GROUP BY` clause is the challenge. As soon as I tell the report writer to average the price, it adds all columns to the `GROUP BY`, I don't have control over that. I'm wondering if there is some kind of work around where I can aggregate subqueries without using group by in the outer query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've referred to subqueries and outer queries but nothing in the above appears to be either of those. This makes me wonder if you need to add a correlation condition. Also notice that the `Price` aggregate was not automatically added to the grouping columns. So I'm not sure I'm wondering if the extra parentheses or some unsupported syntax is causing that.

```
SELECT View_QB_SalesOrderLine.Mfr, View_QB_SalesOrderLine.CatalogNo,
    AVG("SPA Cost UOM" *
      CASE "Price UOM" + "SPA Cost UOM"
        WHEN 'EM' THEN 0.001
        WHEN 'EC' THEN 0.01
        WHEN 'CM' THEN 0.01
        WHEN 'CE' THEN 100
        WHEN 'MC' THEN 100
        WHEN 'ME' THEN 1000
        ELSE 1
      EN) AS "SPA Cost Conv",
    AVG(Price) AS Price
    /* , "Price UOM" -- this is not valid here */
FROM View_QB_SalesOrderLine
GROUP BY Mfr, CatalogNo
ORDER BY Mfr, CatalogNo
```

Long ago I worked with a query tool that would reorganize line breaks so when using comments it was safer to use the bracketed form `/* */` rather than end-of-line `--`. You might want to strip out my commented line entirely.

Comment: That's interesting it doesn't add the `PRICE` to the `GROUP BY`, I hadn't noticed that. I like the logic you used for the conversion, I'm going to plug that in. Is it more efficient that way? I can't just plug in the query you wrote though due to how the tool works. I can only add an expression that will return one column, it seems that when I write an expression it is treated as a subquery (that is where the extra parentheses come in around the `CASE` expression. To demonstrate, here's what happens when I create an empty query and add one expression: (too long I will post in next comment.)

Comment: `SELECT [Expr 1] = (SELECT *
FROM  [View_QB_SalesOrderLine])
FROM ` I only wrote the `SELECT *
FROM  [View_QB_SalesOrderLine]`, the rest was system generated.

Comment: Please take a look at the Report Writer image in the original post if you want to see what the GUI looks like. Might help with what I'm struggling to explain.

Comment: @Ryan No efficiency isn't a concern there. What if you just use the case expression alone and then tell the report writer to aggregate it as you did with the price column?

Comment: OMG...I swear I had tried that and it failed before, but I just tried it again and that works! So simple! I must have had some syntax error when I tried before. Troubleshooting in this tool can be so difficult! Thanks so much for helping me get there!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Group BY
```

in your code based on the requirement I believe in your case that would be item sold

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just updated the post actually showing the query using group by that keeps causing errors. Wondering if you might have any thoughts?